# using groupby clause on data retrieving from multiple table shows "not a groupby expression"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

`select u.UM_TOKEN_NO ,u.UM_FULLNAME,u.SECTOR, u.department_name,t.TS_PROJECT_CODE,sum(t.TS_TOTAL_HRS)
    from prm_user_master u , prm_time_sheet t 
    WHERE (u.UM_TOKEN_NO = t.ts_token_no
    AND t.ts_week_no BETWEEN 35 and 40) 
    GROUP BY t.TS_PROJECT_CODE;`

[image]

I want to get data where I want sum of total hours for each `TS_PROJECT_CODE`.

Comment: Provide the sample data of what is the data that you are getting and what is the data that you are expecting

Comment: @viki888 I have attached image in my question

Comment: @viki888 I am expectin data for each UM_TOKEN_NO and TS_PROJECT_CODE sum of total hours in single record

Comment: Then remove fields **u.UM_FULLNAME,u.SECTOR, u.department_name** from **SELECT** and include **UM_TOKEN_NO** and **TS_PROJECT_CODE** in **GROUP BY** clause

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I solved my query..

Comment: Then post your own answer to your question, which would help others

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      u.UM_TOKEN_NO,
      u.UM_FULLNAME,
      u.SECTOR,
      u.department_name,
      t.TS_PROJECT_CODE,
      sum(t.TS_TOTAL_HRS)
from prm_user_master u
 INNER JOIN  prm_time_sheet t ON u.UM_TOKEN_NO = t.ts_token_no
where t.ts_week_no BETWEEN 35 and 40
GROUP BY u.UM_TOKEN_NO,u.UM_FULLNAME,
         u.SECTOR,u.department_name,t.TS_PROJECT_CODE;
```

Given all column names in group by clause as in select query except the `SUM(t.TS_TOTAL_HRS)` column and it worked fine...